# How to call Base crm REST api in php using cURL?

Tags: php, api, rest, curl

I am facing problem using Base crm REST API in php.

Base crm is providing some code for REST API [here](http://dev.futuresimple.com/) which is

```
 curl -X POST -H "X-Pipejump-Auth:auth-token" \
-H "Accept:application/xml" \
-H "Content-Type:application/json" \
--data "{\"contact\" : { \"last_name\" : \"Barowsky\", \
  \"first_name\" : \"Foo\", \"is_organisation\" : \"false\" }}" \
  https://sales.futuresimple.com/api/v1/contacts/
```

Now can anybody please help me How to use this in php using cURL.

I have reached upto this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
   'Content-Type: application/xml',
   'Accept: application/xml',
  'Connection: Keep-Alive' ));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array("Expect:  "));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Base has released API V2 (https://developers.getbase.com/), along with a library for PHP: https://github.com/basecrm/basecrm-php. I recommend using it rather than the snippet below.

It's been a while, but let's give it a go.

I recommend using json rather than xml, both for request and response.

```
<?php

$token = "your_api_token";

$headers = array(
  "X-Pipejump-Auth: " . $token,
  "Content-Type: application/json",
  "Accept: application/json",
);

$curl = curl_init();
$url = "https://sales.futuresimple.com/api/v1/contacts.json";

$data = array(
  "contact" => array("first_name" => "My", "last_name" => "Contact")
);
$data_string = json_encode($data);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);

$resp = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);

printf($resp);

?>
```